# A summation inside of the expected value operator

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is part of the solution to my homework, which I could not wrap my head around.
Given are $X_n$ random variables n = 1,2,...,N which are independent and Gaussian distributed with known mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Also given is an estimator for the mean value: ${\hat\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x(n)$.

And then we have the following: 
$\operatorname{E}[(X_n - \mu)(\hat\mu - \mu)] = \operatorname{E}[(X_n - \mu)\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(X_n - \mu)] = \frac{1}{N}Var(X_n) = \frac{1}{N}\sigma^2$

It seems as if inside the expectation: $\sum_{n=1}^{N}(X_n - \mu)$ equals $(X_n - \mu)$. Does this make sense? What am I missing?

Comment: Is that *really* the solution as written out by your instructor?

Answer (score 4):

The missing part of the solution is

\begin{align*}
E\left((X_n - \mu) \sum_j (X_j - \mu)\right)
= E\left(\sum_j (X_n - \mu)(X_j - \mu) \right)
\\ = \sum_j E[(X_n - \mu)(X_j - \mu)]
= \sum_j \mbox{Cov}(X_j, X_n)
\end{align*}

and the covariance of the terms in the summation are all equal to zero (by independence) except when $n = j$, in which case we get $\mbox{Var}(X_n)$. Part of the problem with the solution as written is that it is using the same index for the particular $X_n$ and as the summation index $\sum_n (X_n - \mu)$.

Note also that the Gaussian assumption is irrelevant; all that matter is that the variance exists.

Comment: (+1) As written, the "solution" is a pedagogical nightmare, not only from the bizarre use of the same indexing variable but also from leaving out the *important* steps and concepts for arriving at the solution.

Comment: Like @cardinal said.

Comment: guy, thanks for your reply! Helped a lot. :)